# Exact Differential Equations (1)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It would be great if someone could show how does $(15.43)$ follow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side of $(15.42)$ evaluates to

$$\left[b_{n-1}\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+\cdots+b_0\frac{dy}{dx}\right]+\left[b_{n-1}'\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+b_0'y\right]$$

$$=b_{n-1}\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+[b_{n-2}+b_{n-1}']\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+[b_0+b_1']\frac{dy}{dx}+b_0'y$$

$$=b_0'y+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}[b_{i-1}+b'_{i}]\frac{d^iy}{dx^i}+b_{n-1}\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

The left hand side of $(15.42)$ is

$$a_0 y+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\frac{d^iy}{dx^i}+a_n\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}f\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

so, comparing coefficients, we need

$$a_0=b_0',\qquad a_{i}=b_{i-1}+b'_{i}\quad \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\},\qquad a_n=b_{n-1}.$$

Thus

$$a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^ia_i^{(i)}+(-1)^na_n^{(n)}=b_0'+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i[b_{i-1}^{(i)}+b_{i}^{(i+1)}]+(-1)^nb_{n-1}.\tag{1}$$

We need to show the right hand side of $(1)$ is zero.

Notice that most of the terms in the middle sum of $(1)$ cancel:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i[b_{i-1}^{(i)}+b_{i}^{(i+1)}]=-[b_0'+b_1'']+[b_1''+b_2''']-\cdots+(-1)^{n-2}[b_{n-3}^{(n-2)}+b_{n-2}^{(n-1)}]+(-1)^{n-1}[b_{n-2}^{(n-1)}+b_{n-1}^{(n)}]$$

$$=-b_0'+(-1)^{n-1}b_{n-1}^{(n)}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$$

Therefore the right-hand side of $(1)$ is

$$b_0'+[-b_0'+(-1)^{n-1}b_{n-1}^{(n)}]+(-1)^nb_{n-1}^{(n)}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following principle:

> Suppose $f\in L^1([a,b])$ and $\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f\varphi\text{ d}x} = 0$ for all $\varphi\in C_C^{\infty}((a,b))$. Then $f = 0$ almost everywhere in $[a,b]$.

Here, $C_C^{\infty}((a,b))$ consists of all infinitely differentiable functions $\varphi$ on $(a,b)$ such that $\text{supp}(\varphi) = \overline{\{x\in(a,b):\varphi(x)\ne 0\}}\subset(a,b)$, or equivalently that $\varphi$ vanishes outside the interval $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Now let $\varphi\in C_C^{\infty}((a,b))$. Integrating (15.42) with $y = \varphi$ over $[a,b]$ yields
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{a_k\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}}\right)\text{ d}x} = \int\limits_{a}^{b}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{b_k\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}}\right)\text{ d}x} =  \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{b_k\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}}\right)\Bigg|_{a}^{b} = 0.$$
The last equality holds since $\varphi = 0$ outside some interval $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$, and hence all of its derivatives do as well.

Now, for any $1\le k\le n$, integration by parts on $a_k\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}$ yields
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}{a_k(x)\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}(x)\text{ d}x} = \left(a_k\frac{d^{k-1}\varphi}{dx^{k-1}}\right)\Bigg|_{a}^{b} - \int\limits_{a}^{b}{a_k'(x)\frac{d^{k-1}\varphi}{dx^{k-1}}(x)\text{ d}x} = 0 - \int\limits_{a}^{b}{a_k'(x)\frac{d^{k-1}\varphi}{dx^{k-1}}(x)\text{ d}x} $$
where the boundary terms vanish for the same reason as above. Repeating this $k$ times, we get
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}{a_k(x)\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}(x)\text{ d}x} = \int\limits_{a}^{b}{(-1)^ka_k^{(k)}(x)\varphi(x)\text{ d}x}. $$
Hence, we have
$$ 0 = \int\limits_{a}^{b}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{a_k(x)\frac{d^k\varphi}{dx^k}(x)}\text{ d}x} = \int\limits_{a}^{b}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^ka_k^{(k)}(x)\varphi(x)}\text{ d}x}.$$
If we let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^ka_k^{(k)}(x)}$, we then have $\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f(x)\varphi(x)\text{ d}x} = 0$ for all $\varphi\in C_C^{\infty}((a,b))$. By the principle above, it follows that $f = 0$ almost everywhere in $(a,b)$. (If the coefficients $a_k$ are assumed to be, e.g., $C^k$, then we can conclude that $f$ is identically zero, as desired.)